# Intersection of hypersphere with hyperplane

Tags: geometry

Suppose we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n$ a positive integer greater than or equal to $2$. Also, let $S$ be a $m$-dimensional hypersphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $1 \leq m \leq n-1$, and let $P$ be a $k$-dimensional hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where again $1 \leq k \leq n-1$. For those who don't know, a hypersphere is the analogue of circles and spheres, and a hyperplane is the analogue of lines and planes. My question is, is the intersection of $S$ and $P$ either empty, a single point, or a $p$-dimensional hypersphere, where $0 \leq p \leq min(m,k-1)$, and all cases are possible? Note, a $0$-dimensional hypersphere is just a set of two distinct points.

Comment: We have to start with the classic case where $n=3$. The dimension of an hyperplane of $\mathbb R^n$ is $n-1$. Besides, it's awkward to work in $\mathbb R^n$. It is better to choose a reference point suitable for the case you are interested in and only then bring you back to $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Usually, the prefix "hyper" refers to a codimension 1 submanifolds. In your situation, these are just spheres and affine subspaces.

Comment: Actually, now I realized not all cases are possible. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a plane can intersect a sphere either at the empty set, a single point, or a circle, but not at two distinct points (which is a $0$-dimensional hypersphere). So, some other expression besides $0$ should replace the left hand side of my chain of inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall what happens in space E of dimension $3$. Consider a sphere $S$ with center $0$(We then consider the space $E_0$ pointed to $0$) and radius $R$. Let $H$ be a plane (hyperplane of three-dimensional space) and $d$ be the distance from $0$ to $H$. Two cases :

- $d\geq R : H\cap S$ is then reduced to a point or empty;
- $d< R: $ let $O$ be the orthogonal projection of $0$ on $H$; according to the Pythagorean theorem, $$\forall M\in H\cap S, OM^2=R^2-d^2$$
  $H\cap S$ is then a sphere in $H$ of radius $\sqrt{R^2-d^2}$, i.e. a circle.

Reasoning in dimension 3 extends without any problem to any dimension, where we also have a Euclidean structure, the Pythagorean theorem, etc